# Can COUNTIFS include simple formula as criteria (x - y > z)

Tags: excel-2010, countif, formulas

Excel 2010

I have a COUNTIFS formula I'm creating.  So far, I have the following, which works great:

```
=COUNTIFS(Manager, $A7, Created Date,"<="& variable date, Closed Date, "<="& variable date)
```

The problem is I need to add another if-clause that counts only if 'variable date - Created Date > 14'.  I can't figure out if it's possible or how I would do it.  If it is possible, what criteria_range would I use and what would be the proper syntax (including quote marks) for the formula portion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, after some additional research, I ended up with the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Manager=$A7),--(variable date-Created Date>14),--(Closed Date>variable date))
```

I don't completely understand the resulting formula but it did do what I needed it to do.